# Using statannotations how can I pass in stats_params to modify the statistics test?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, seaborn

I'm trying to perform a one-tailed students t-test_ind and need to modify the stats_params but am unable to do so.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
plotting_parameters = {
    'data':        df1, 
    'x':           R, 
    'y':           TMD, 
    'hue':         None, #R, 
    'hue_order':   None, #[Eq, Po], 
    'order':       [Eq, Po], 
    'ci':          'sd', 
    'errcolor':    'black', 
    'capsize':     0.2, 
}

annotator_parameters = {
    'loc':                  'outside', 
    'test':                 't-test_ind', 
    'text_format':          'star', 
    'line_offset':          0.0, 
    'line_height':          0.015, 
    'stats_params':         {'alternative': 'greater'}
}

pairs                 = [((Eq, Po))]

# Barplot
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.barplot(**plotting_parameters)

annotator = Annotator(ax, pairs, **plotting_parameters)

annotator.configure(**annotator_parameters)
annotator.apply_and_annotate()

ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
ax = sns.despine() # takes the lines off on the right and top of the graph
```

inside the dictionary `annotator_parameters` the variable `stats_params` doesn't seem to be passed through to `scipy.stats`.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

When I used to use `statannot` I would pass the variable through and was able to get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply `stats_params` to the `apply_test` method, not the `configure` method. Unfortunately, the [`apply_and_annotate`](https://github.com/trevismd/statannotations/blob/bc0c4b8c9565c44427c633c4660ea04b6753292e/statannotations/Annotator.py#L243-L247) method doesn't take parameters, so you'll have to call `apply_test` and `annotate` individually:

```
annotator.apply_test(alternative='greater')
annotator.annotate()
```